# What is this javascript regex doing?

Tags: regex

I found this on some javascript code and wondering what it's matching.

```
var i = /^tags: ?((?:.*, ?)*.*)$/m.exec(e.details);
```

Comment: Stuff like `tags: foo, bar, baz`

Comment: [tadaaaa](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28%3Fm%29tags%3A+%3F%28%28%3F%3A.*%2C+%3F%29*.*%29%24)

Answer (score 0):

```
^ //start of the string
tags: //4 characters: "tags"
 ? //an optional space
((?:.* // 0 or more of any character except a newline
, ?) //a comma, then an optional space
* // all the stuff on the previous 2 lines, repeated 0 or more times
.*) //a capturing group of any character, repeated 0 or more times
$ //end of the string
```

basically, a list of tags separated by commas.

This regex happens to accept any string that starts with "tags:"

It tries to capture the stuff after the colon. (Note: I don't think it does what the author wants it to do, since `.*` is greedy.) It captures it all in one group, instead of one tag per group.